# Ion-Select name too large to display

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, css-selectors, pipe

I am trying to show a list of names into a ion-select. But when the moment to show the names they are too large to display enterly. 
[Here there is an image that show the situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/msbZV.png)

Is there any way to display the entire name using some pipe (like a br) or some CSS?

I've tried some options but none of them were satisfactory.

Any suggestion would be appreciated. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
.alert-md .alert-radio-label{
    white-space: inherit !important;
}
```

change the white space to inherit or initial.

add the above code in **app.scss** and not in your-component.scss